# Microsoft edge extension package command not working

Tags: microsoft-edge, makeappx

I have been using the following [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/extensions/guides/packaging/using-manifoldjs-to-package-extensions) from Microsoft to package an extension.  Was able to generate appmanifest.xml file using manifoldjs. The problem I am facing is with the last command wherein after some modifications in the xml file I have to run this command `manifoldjs -l debug -p edgeextension package <EXTENSION NAME>\edgeextension\manifest\`.

Below is the commandline output which shows I am unable to do aything further. The execution pauses (doesn't terminate/finish) and nothing happens.

```
$ manifoldjs -l debug -p edgeextension package MSGappShortName/edgeextension/manifest/
[debug] manifoldjs  : Loading platform module: manifoldjs-edgeextension
[debug] manifoldjs  : Packaging the 'Microsoft Edge Extension Platform' app...
[info ] edgeextension: Packaging the Microsoft Edge Extension Platform app...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the same commands with the new version (renamed to PWABuilder), without issue. https://github.com/pwa-builder  or npm-install pwabuilder.